# IndexError: Replacement index 11 out of range for positional args tuple

Tags: python

why am i getting this error?

```
print("{10} {8} {2} {11} {4} {3} {6} {9} {7} {1} {5}".format('in', 'know', 'bring', 'to', 'students.', 'out', 'best', 'teachers', 'the', 'Good', 'how'))
```

Error -

```
IndexError: Replacement index 11 out of range for positional args tuple
```

Comment: Start counting at 0, not 1.

Answer (score 1):

This would work for you,

```
print("{9} {7} {1} {10} {3} {2} {5} {8} {6} {0} {4}".format('in', 'know', 'bring', 'to', 'students.', 'out', 'best', 'teachers', 'the', 'Good', 'how'))
```

The error was because you had the indices range in [1, 11] instead of [0,10].